# How to change default delphi docked form title height?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I dock form to the TPanel using standard delphi docking functions. And the title of docked form looks like this 
[image]

How can I modify its appearance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default appearance comes from [`TCaptionedDockTree`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.CaptionedDockTree.TCaptionedDockTree). You can write your own descendant and assign it to [`DefaultDockTreeClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.DefaultDockTreeClass) to replace it.
To change the caption height, override [`AdjustCaptionRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.CaptionedDockTree.TCaptionedDockTree.AdjustCaptionRect). To change the actual drawing of the caption, override [`GetDockCaptionDrawer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.CaptionedDockTree.TCaptionedDockTree.GetDockCaptionDrawer) to return your own descendant of `TDockCaptionDrawer` with overriden `DrawDockCaption` and/or `DockCaptionHitTest` methods.